# How can Jesus (the word become flesh) have a God? Does God have a God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity, divinity

All these verses (and many more) say he does.John 5:44 the one and only God. John 17:3, 2 Cor 1:3, Eph 1:3, Col 1:3, 2 Cor 11:31, Rom 15:6, Rom 1:7 the God of our Lord Jesus. 1 Pet 1:3 Heb 1:8-9 God anointed Jesus. Jesus gives the kingdom to God and Father 1 Cor 15:24.

If Jesus has a God - which scripture clearly says he does, how do we explain trintarian co-equality?

Even when ascended, in Rev, Jesus is still subordinate to God, clearly separate from God Rev 5:13, 6:16, 7:9, 7:10, 21:22 and many other places showing the Lamb is not God, and therefor, God is not the Lamb.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. This question covers the general topic of Jesus referring to the Father as his God. If you still have follow up questions I'd suggest you ask them individually one verse at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I hadn't noticed that one. However I don't think it is answered with any weighty biblical support. If the answers must come from other than the bible then that is another question.

Comment: You can also try the [hermeneutics.se] site, though they have different rules to this site.